# Progress-bar for Ruby Upload

Tags: ruby, progress-bar

I have a Dropbox CLI api that performs chunked uploads, using the [ruby-progressbar](https://github.com/jfelchner/ruby-progressbar) for an indicator for how the upload is going.

It works fine when the file is under 4MB (the default chunk size for the chunked upload) but it has issues with anything over that:

```
from /opt/rubies/2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-progressbar-1.2.0/lib/ruby-progressbar/components/progressable.rb:45:in `progress='
from /opt/rubies/2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-progressbar-1.2.0/lib/ruby-progressbar/base.rb:138:in `with_progressables'
from /opt/rubies/2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-progressbar-1.2.0/lib/ruby-progressbar/base.rb:45:in `block in progress='
from /opt/rubies/2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-progressbar-1.2.0/lib/ruby-progressbar/base.rb:148:in `with_update'
from /opt/rubies/2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-progressbar-1.2.0/lib/ruby-progressbar/base.rb:45:in `progress='
from /Users/peterso/Projects/slipsquare/lib/slipsquare/middleware/chunked_upload.rb:20:in `block in call'
from /opt/rubies/2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/dropbox-api-petems-1.1.0/lib/dropbox-api/client/files.rb:50:in `chunked_upload'
```

I assume I'm doing something silly with the total calculation, where I'm still adding to the progress-bar's total even when the upload has hit full size and complete.

But I've been looking at it for a while and I cant seem to find a way of getting the current progress from the bar and going "If progressbar.current_size + offset > total, finish progressbar".

The code looks like this:

```
file_name = env['chunked_upload_file_name']
contents  = File.open(env['chunked_upload_file_name'])
total_size = File.size(env['chunked_upload_file_name'])

say "Total Size: #{total_size} bytes"
upload_progress_bar = ProgressBar.create(:title => "Upload progress",
  :format => '%a <%B> %p%% %t',
  :starting_at => 0,
  :total => total_size)

response = env['dropbox-client'].chunked_upload file_name, contents do |offset, upload|
  upload_progress_bar.progress += offset
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the current `offset` to the `progress` in each iteration. Imagine you have a 10K file and upload it in 10 chunks. In the first iteration our `offset` is `0`, in the next `1`, in the third `2`, then `3`. Since you sum up the `offsets` your `progress` will display `60%`, although it has only done `40%`.

Instead of adding the `offset` to the `progress`, just set the `progress` to the current `offset`:

```
upload_progress_bar.progress = offset
```

Or more correct, because the offset tell what was uploaded before the current chunk was uploaded.

```
upload_progress_bar.progress = offset + default_chunk_size
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't just think of doing the offset as the progress, feel pretty silly now. Thanks! :)